# Big Integer arithmetic

Tags: c, biginteger, integer-arithmetic

I want to know the different techniques that are used for performing arithmetic operations on very large integers in C. One that I know of is using string to hold a number and define operations add, subtract etc. for it. I am not interested in using libraries, this question is purely for knowledge. Please suggest any other such methods/techniques used.

Comment: have you look < http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture20.html >

Answer (score 3):

You can go as low level as representing your integers as an array of bytes, and do all the operations (like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division or comparison) just like a CPU does them, at word level.

The simplest algorithms are for addition and subtraction, where you simply add or subtract the digits in sequence, carrying as necessary.

Negative numbers can be represented in 2's complement.

For comparison, you just compare the high order digits until a difference is found.

For multiplication the most straightforward algorithm (and slowest) you can implement is repeated addition.

For division, things are a little more complicated than multiplication, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm

A common application for this is public-key cryptography, whose algorithms commonly employ arithmetic with integers having hundreds of digits.

Check the OpenSSL BIGNUM documentation for this: https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use 3 linked lists, one for number A, one for number B and one for the result.

You would then read each digit as a character input from the user, make it an integer and and save it to a new node in the list, corresponding to the number you read at the moment.

And Finally you would just write as functions the operations for adding,subtracting etc.
In each  you would follow their respective algorithm you learned at school, starting from the LSB node, going up to the MSB node, always keeping at mind the base powers of each number(1 node * 10^0, 2 node * 10^1, 3 node * 10^2, ...,n node * 10^n ).